# How do I get the day month and year columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to solve a regression problem trying to predict house prices, but the data frame has a non-numeric `date` column and is somewhat poorly coded. I don't want to drop the column directly. I want to get `day`, `month`, and `year` information in new columns. What should I do?

The column looks like this:

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a poorly formatted string, its a timestamp.  Pandas can convert this to a datetime object for you.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['20141013T000000','20141209T000000']})

f['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['year'] = df['date'].dt.year
df['month'] = df['date'].dt.month
df['day'] = df['date'].dt.day
```

Output

```
        date  year  month  day
0 2014-10-13  2014     10   13
1 2014-12-09  2014     12    9
```

Answer (score 1):

First you want to convert the column to a correct datetime format. In pandas you can use:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

Then you want to create new columns for the different parts of the date:

```
df['year'] = df['date'].dt.year
df['month'] = df['date'].dt.month
df['day'] = df['date'].dt.day
df['weekday'] = df['date'].dt.weekday
```

Answer (score 0):

this solution does exactly that, i tried it with your dataframe example.

```
from datetime import datetime
# Here df is your dataframe
def process_date(x):
  date = datetime.strptime(x.split('T')[0], "%Y%m%d")
  return pd.Series([date.day, date.month, date.year])

df[['day','month','year']] = df.date.apply(lambda x: process_date(x))
df = df.drop('date', axis=1)
```

output:

```
day month   year
0   13  10  2014
1   9   12  2014
```